# Why Class Diagram methods are defined in the same class?

Tags: java, spring-boot, oop, class-diagram, class-design

In class diagram representation, the fields and the class related methods are shown on the diagram. However, when converting the diagram to a class, I see that these methods are shown like an interface method as shown:

```
public class Account {

    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String phone;
    private List<CreditCard> creditCards;

    public boolean addProduct(Product product);
    public boolean addProductReview(ProductReview review);
    public boolean resetPassword();
}
```

Is it the class implementation that is normally used? Or just an higher level implementation? Because normally, I would implement `addProduct(Product product)` and the other methods in the service of this class (`AccountService`). Is it wrong?

Comment: The code has been generated in a way that is idiosyncratic to your UML tool.  As shown, it is not valid Java.  Each method in a class must either have an implementation or be declared `abstract`, and if any method is declared `abstract` then so must be the class itself.  Only you can say which way to go to correct the code for your purposes.

Comment: Yes, but it is generally shown as shown above. In that case: **1.** I think it is a general convention for showing class implementation of Class Diagrams, right?

Comment: I would like to ask, which uml tool to use

Comment: **2.** When I make the implementation, I keep all the fields in my `Account` entity and remove methods from `Account` class. Then, implement these methods to `AccountService` class in my Spring Boot apps. Is there any problem with this approach?

Comment: @时间只会一直走 I did not use UML, it is generally shown like that. The example is on https://www.sartiano.it/marco/diigo/System%20Design/Grokking%20the%20Object%20Oriented%20Design%20Interview.html

Comment: @JohnBollinger Do you have an idea about my questions #1 and #2 ?

Comment: @时间只会一直走 CanCinCon, are you there amigo?

Comment: @fredrick: (1) No. Where earlier I said it's "idiosyncratic", that means it's specific to your tool.  (2) If you want there to be an `AccountService` class bearing those methods, then it's odd that you did not model it that way in your UML.  If you're asking about Spring conventions then I can't help you, but others around here can.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Would you please post a proper Class Diagram with just one field and one method and its proper implementation example?

Comment: Take a look at this   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html   and take a look at this   https://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application   , if you are referring to representations of the contents of a class in a tutorial, they are spurious for use in any program, they only represent contents that is for the purpose of the tutorial.  Here's what it should more appear when written finished.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TableDemoProject/src/components/TableDemo.java

Comment: Thanks for links Samuel, but I am just wondering the proper place for the implementation of methods. So, for Spring Boot apps, is it the Service or Util methods rather than entity classes?

Comment: I don't really understand your question: today UML is understood as a tool for documenting and a quick overview of (object oriented) code - the abilities to generate code from it are - improvable - to say it nicely. So do you want to know how to model your classes, or if your usual class design is OK? I really don't get it. Above code does not compile in Java. so maybe you want to know the gap to compiling code?

Comment: I just want to get idea about transforming a Class Diagram to Java classes / entities. You may just give an example with 1-2 classes and 1-2 fields and methods. That's it, but would be so useful.

Comment: I think that the explanation in the answer from @Christophe together with the code you posted, everything is said: a class diagram contains multiple classes and describes their members: fields and methods. And sometimes also relations between the classes. Nothing about behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UML is design agnostic.  If you define a class like:

[image]

It is understood like the code you've shown, and any decent code generator would generate the code you have.

If you want to keep your domain class `Account`  with only data and separate the domain logic into an `AccountService` class, it is your right, but you'll have to model two distinct classes in UML.  This design approach is by the way called the [anemic domain model](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html) (see also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_domain_model)), and,  like it or not, it is considered as an anti-pattern.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. But, I am a little bit confused. Could you please clarify me about these points? >>>

Comment: **1.** As far as I see, there is no problem regarding to this class implementation for UML, but normally I think we do not implement such an entity class that has these kind of methods. Right?

Comment: **2.** Is the idea "moving these methods" to interface/service in a Spring Boot app is ok or not? Could you pls explain a little bit more by giving some examples?

Comment: @fredrick 1. there is a whole lot of DDD that implement classes in that way, and that let repository classes make the wiring between behaviorless DB data and full-blown encapsulated objets. There are many more other approaches that also use such kind of classes.

Comment: 2. The anemic domain model  is [popular with spring](https://dzone.com/articles/anemic-domain-model-in-typical-spring-projects-1).  But it's [not a fatality](https://medium.com/@nikos_k/how-to-avoid-the-anemic-domain-model-with-spring-and-hibernate-35495d6e2e94).

Comment: 3. My point here is not to judge anemic domain model, nor spring, nor to tell you to design things in another way. No: your code, your choice. My point is to say that UML is agnostic and allows modelers to represent the classes they think are needed to solve a problem.  Consequently you should not expect UML tools to generate other classes than those that are modeled, and if you need two, you should model both ;-)

Comment: As a result, can we say that **"A class diagram does not directly show entity or service classes and keep the related fields and methods inside a class. Based on the situations, we can keep the fields in our entity class and move methods to the related services. But sometimes, it is also possible to implement that methods inside the class shown in the diagram."** Is it a valid approach?

Comment: @fredrick unfortunately, that would be a redefinition of UML.  What you can say is that the UML diagram foresees the entity's operations to be provided by the class, but that you decided to adapt this design in the implementation in the way that ...

Comment: Could you please post a Java (Spring Boot) implementation of a basic 2-3 classes from Class Diagram? It would be really much more useful than words and I do not take your more time :)

Comment: @fredrick I Think your original question was about UML classes and their meaning for implementation. I think that my answer fully addresses the topic. In the comment exchange it appears that you now have another question, which is how to implement a proper domain model with Spring Boot without using an anemic domain model. This is a different question, to ask separately